# WHirlpool Super capacity 465 I hear gas at burners but will not ignite even with a match. I hear no gas in oven area

Tags: oven

I recently went to restart the Whirlpool Super Capacity 465 gas oven.  I can hear the gas and feel the gas at the burners.  No clicking and it will not light with a match.  I tried the oven, turned on the heat and hear no gas there at all.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you see the flame being disturbed of the match when you try to light the burner?

Comment: Yes it almost blows it out

Comment: Do you *smell* the gas that's coming out?

Comment: Yes I do but it is faint

Comment: Call the gas company, they have folks that come out and fix this for free. Maintenance of the lines sometimes traps large amounts of air and it can take quite a while to flush. The gas co would rather fix this than having someone blow up there house because they don't have the testers to check if the lines are sealed after the work is done.

Answer (score -1):

WARNING  WARNING*****THIS IS NOT A JOB FOR AN AMATEUR****WARNING  WARNING
I'm going to make a guess here; hopefully it can help.  I wager that somehow a large bubble of air or very low concentrate gas has gotten into the line and is giving you trouble.  If this is true here is the fix.  First ventilate the area very well; open all windows and doors to allow lots of fresh air to the immediate area.  Keep them open.  Now find a point on the gas supply line to the appliance that is accessible and has a union type fitting.  Find the appliance gas shut-off valve. It should be in the area.  Turn it off.  On the down-stream side of the service valve, break this fitting; unscrew this fitting completely. This will allow you to dump a large amount of gas in a short period of time to clear the line effectively under very controlled conditions. Now open the gas valve all the way.  Allow this gas line to vent for 15 to 20-seconds.  The gas should smell like rotten eggs and the smell should get worse as the gas concentrates.  Close the service valve.  Now leave the gas valve in the off position turn and leave the area for a good 4-minutes.  Do not turn on or off any lights in the area.  Basically don't do anything but leave the area.  After the allotted time return and reconnect the gas line tightly.  Reopen the gas service valve.  Now again try to light the appliance.  Hopefully, the results will be different.

WARNING WARNING****THIS IN NOT A JOB FOR AN AMATEUR****WARNING   WARNING

Servicing of the gas lines and gas supply is constantly going on upstream to your gas service.  It is the nature of life.  In the process of doing this, air is a times unintentionally allowed into the system. You may be experiencing one of these times. Good Luck and happy cooking. P.